# Verify access_token provided by Azure Active Directory OAuth provider in Node.js

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory, passport-azure-ad

I've a React Native Client which gets the access_token from Azure Active Directory and then it passes the token in the Node.js API in the header.

In the Node.js API that token is to be verified...

I got a NPM module called azure-ad-jwt,

And I tried to verify the token using this block of code.

```
const aad = require('azure-ad-jwt');
const token = '<<<<My Token>>>>';

aad.verify(token, { audience: 'https://graph.microsoft.com' }, (err, result) => {
  if (result) { console.log('Valid Token'); }
  else if (err) { console.log(err); }
});
```

I don't know whether I've missed anything or something is wrong in my configuration.

I'm getting this error: `JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature`

Although my token is properly getting decoded with all the information.

I don't know why it still throws this error.

It would be great if anyone could rectify this error and help me find a solution on this.

Guys its the token

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFDRWZleFh4amFtUWIzT2VHUTRHdWd2RlhUMlRPNXhaR2s0MEZydnNSYnV6TDlzajdnWUhXNVFuX0pDVHZGRjlzMTRNUndOMWxJSlNGQzVtVm9tMzh6MmxzakpaTnVlcHNLOTc0VEQwZEtneWlBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoibmJDd1cxMXczWGtCLXhVYVh3S1JTTGpNSEdRIiwia2lkIjoibmJDd1cxMXczWGtCLXhVYVh3S1JTTGpNSEdRIn0.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.OreAmua43bv6SDHOoYFnTQl97K4Zoz8PJjlPDGkKoJvUBZgy5HzfPGMutUGMpYfKRkdG_01aUuwG-DJGiFwJzMvpPVyMt3YVldd7Q7mZuP3k9_WVnp32XU7v47HijGxSrdiGVAq6qaZLEqAUs23CupseVsJ6NFTpTuxfDoCEgs8uCqYGlz5-oZvbkyxyQvrP7HBLxDKT0dL-SOLisVERyaJbW9gdQqEhzv9KGbhov_Eq0FIHkjLpJehU7cRF9tXGJF8ISRP71WrYkLwVJMjhnL4YqsPeWfnR9cnOmeSaFKe2OYFC97AMNpMFNV8WAsPpqJHb9HuLKHVmLTLqZPg3Fw
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot verify tokens for Microsoft Graph API. Your front-end needs to acquire an access token for your API, and then you need to check the audience is either your app's client id or App ID URI.

Comment: You mean, I've to manually check it against the APP ID after decoding the token?

Comment: You need to also make sure the audience in the token matches that.

Comment: I'm not getting what you're saying, could you please elaborate it, or maybe try this on the Runkit, if its possible for you I can provide you the token

Comment: What about jwt.io does it say that signature is invalid?

Comment: I'm sharing this token, 
Please help me I'm searching this from past 5 days, its in the question which I've edited

and yes it does show Invalid signature in the jwt.io too

Answer (score 1):

> In the Node.js API that token is to be verified

You want to verify the token for your Node.js API, but your audience is `https://graph.microsoft.com`, you should request the token for the Node.js API, not the microsfot graph API.

Comment: I want to use the Microsoft graph token to access Microsoft graph resources from Node.js API, so when I get token from frontend I want to use the same token (Microsoft token) to authenticate in my api as well rather than creating one seperate token for Node.js API

Comment: @SushantK, you cannot use the node.js API to verify the Microsoft graph token, the   Microsoft graph token should be verified in the Microsoft graph API.

Comment: So what should be the standard way of authentication in Node.js API? if not done using Microsoft Graph token?

Comment: @SushantK, if you verify the token in the node.js API, it will only accept the token that the audience is itself.

Comment: @SushantK, in the StackOverflow, please keep careful about your private information in your post. For the token, you could post the decode part or screenshot that has no private information.